# Mouse hook getting disconnected

Tags: c#, .net, mouse

I'm trying to implement a color picker that takes the color from a pixel everywhere in the screen.
To do that I'm planning to use a global mouse hook to listen to WM_MOUSEMOVE in order to update the color as the mouse is moved around and listen to mouse clicks to confirm (WM_LBUTTONDOWN) or cancel(WM_RBUTTONDOWN) the operation.

I have followed one of the many tutorials around and I came up with this (in a Console Application, just to test out if the process works):

```
static IntPtr hook;
static bool click;
static NativeMethods.LowLevelHookStruct llhs;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  hook = NativeMethods.SetWindowsHookEx(NativeMethods.WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookCallback, (IntPtr)null, 0);
  if (hook != IntPtr.Zero)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hook Set");
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", hook, llhs.pt.x, llhs.pt.y);

      if(click) Console.WriteLine("click!");
      click = false;

      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250); 
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
public static IntPtr MouseHookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
  if (nCode >= 0)
  {
    NativeMethods.LowLevelHookStruct hookStruct = (NativeMethods.LowLevelHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(NativeMethods.LowLevelHookStruct));

    if (NativeMethods.MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEMOVE == (NativeMethods.MouseMessages)wParam)
    {
      llhs = hookStruct;
    }

    if (NativeMethods.MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (NativeMethods.MouseMessages)wParam)
    {
      click = true;
    }
    else if (NativeMethods.MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN == (NativeMethods.MouseMessages)wParam)
    {
    }
  }

  return NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

NativeMethods is simply a class where I keep all the DllImport related stuff.

Once I run the console application, the mouse cursor gets stuck for a couple of seconds, and in the console I get this - even while the cursor *is* stuck

```
Hook Set
3945554872 0 0
3945554872 0 0
3945554872 0 0
3945554872 0 0
...
```

Going at it in debug, it seems that my hook is never called, not even once.
Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: I removed a tag from the title of your question. Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) why.

Comment: Ah, forgot about it. thanks :)

Comment: A WH_MOUSE_LL hook requires a message loop so Windows can safely call the hook callback.  Application.Run() in a .NET program.  Most easily had from a Winforms or WPF project or one of the many libraries that do this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Hans Passant comment I moved my test code to a WinForms application, and callbacks started coming.

Then it was just a matter to find out that the callback was being garbage collected, so all I had to do was to change

```
hook = NativeMethods.SetWindowsHookEx(NativeMethods.WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookCallback, (IntPtr)null, 0);
```

to

```
private NativeMethods.LowLevelHookProc _hookCallback;

...

_hookCallback = new NativeMethods.LowLevelHookProc(MouseHookCallback);
hook = NativeMethods.SetWindowsHookEx(NativeMethods.WH_MOUSE_LL, _hookCallback, (IntPtr)null, 0);
```

in order to keep a reference to the callback so that it would not be GCed.